# How to save ram memory when using Bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, ram

I'm doing a little game and i want to load Bitmaps,What is a good way to load the pictures without knowing how frequently a player may use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). Don't forget to check out the other chapers.